# How do I insert a string right after pattern in awk

Tags: awk

I want to insert a `string` right after `pattern` match without specifying the field (if possible) since the `regex` can be at unknown position in file.txt.

file.txt

```
This is *regex* in 3rd field
*regex* in first field
another line with *regex*
```

I want the output to be something like this

```
This is regex *new string* in 3rd field
regex *new string* in first field
another line with regex *new string*
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
awk ' /regex/ { print $1, $2, $3 " new string", $4, $5, $6} ' file.txt
```

however, I know it isn't the suitable way of doing this.

I'm new to awk, by the way.

Comment: Are `*` part of input or there just to highlight the pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sub` (or `gsub` if you want multiple replacements on the same line) to make a regex substitution on the whole line (`$0`):

```
awk '{ sub(/\*regex\*/, "regex *new string*") }1'
```

Output

```
This is regex *new string* in 3rd field
regex *new string* in first field
another line with regex *new string*
```

The same thing using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/\*regex\*/regex *new string*/'   # sub
sed 's/\*regex\*/regex *new string*/g'  # gsub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Like this, using `field` as required

```
 awk '/regex/{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "regex") $i=$i" new string"}1' file
```

#### Output

```
This is regex new string in 3rd field
regex new string in first field
another line with regex new string
```

###### Note: if the `*` are literal in your input, use `($i == "*regex*")`

Answer (score 1):

The value of the matched text can be back referenced in a `gsub` replacement using the `&` operator, allowing the match to be replaced with a copy of itself followed by the field separator and the required new string:

**test file (peter.txt)**

```
Peter is a man
it was Peter who first invented spam
peter is a naughty boy
```

(note Peter occurs with both upper and lower case P)

**awk command**

```
awk '{gsub(/[Pp]eter/, "& new string", $0)}1' peter.txt
```

The `&` is substituted for the value that matched the regex

**output**

```
Peter new string is a man
it was Peter new string who first invented spam
peter new string is a naughty boy
```

The `awk` command could be refined to allow the replacement text to be passed as an argument:

```
awk -v 'txt=Parker' '{gsub(/[Pp]eter/, "& "txt, $0)}1' peter.txt
```

**output**

```
Peter Parker is a man
it was Peter Parker who first invented spam
peter Parker is a naughty boy
```

Answer (score 1):

### if `*regex*` as a fixed string actually exists in the input :

```
 echo 'This is *regex* in 3rd field
*regex* in first field
another line with *regex*' |
```

> ```
>  nawk NF=NF FS='[*]regex[*]' OFS='regex new string'
> ```

```
This is regex new string in 3rd field
regex new string in first field
another line with regex new string
```

---

### if there are no edge cases to deal with, like having `"Petersburg"` within the input, even for mixed case input

```
echo 'Peter is a man
it was Peter who first invented spam
peter is a naughty boy'
```

> ```
>  gawk NF=NF FS='eter' OFS='eter Parker'
> ```

```
Peter Parker is a man
it was Peter Parker who first invented spam
peter Parker is a naughty boy
```

---

### this works for all instances except when the matching pattern is exactly at end of line, since 2nd `gsub()` in the main code pads on an extra trailing space that needs to be removed via another call to `sub()`

```
 echo 'Peter is a man
it was Peter who first invented spam Petersburg
peter is a naughty boy' |
```

> ```
>  mawk 'gsub("[Pp]eter( |$)", "&\5Parker \5")^_ + gsub("[ ]?\5"," ")'
> ```

```
Peter Parker is a man
it was Peter Parker who first invented spam Petersburg
peter Parker is a naughty boy
```